# Asp.Net MVC with Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am looking for a good approach for implementing intranet Web Application using Web Api(2) with Asp.net MVC(5).
Application is designed in such a way that we use AngularJS SPA at client side and in server side MVC with Web Api as a single application/web site. MVC is because we have to  restrict the operations based on the security permissions. We don't render the action buttons(eg. Save, Delete etc) when we call MVC controller for views if the user does not have permission. Other operations are utilizing Web API methods to Save, Delete etc,

Basic idea is

MVC Controllers are for generating views with action buttons removed if the user doesn't have permission(html templates for AngularJS).
Data Manipulation is through Web API(AngularJS $http service web api calls)

Questions here

How do we derive an authentication mechanism which we can utilize for both MVC and Web API?
(We can create Authentication filters but we have to create separate filters for MVC and Web API, right?)

Once the user is authenticated how do we share this info with both MVC Controller and Web Api controller instead of validating the user each request from angular js?

Is it possible to use ASP.Net forms authentication for both MVC and WebApi for authentication?. If so how do we do that?. Will forms authetication token validates for both MVC controller and Web Api controllers automatically using [authorize] attribute?

Also I would like to know, is it a good approach mixing MVC with WebApi with in a single application?

Comment: So you don't want to use the built-in authentication (e.g. Identity with Accounts/Roles then use `AuthorizeAttribute`)?

Comment: Yes we can but we need to handle it separately for MVC and Web API, right?

Comment: Is your Web API in a separate server / project than the MVC website?

Comment: Web API and MVC are in single application

Comment: If they are in the same application, they already share the same context (Http/Owin) and can be authenticated the same way. The authorization filter are in different namespaces for Mvc/WebApi but they work the same. In any case, you could create your own authorization filter and implement the interfaces for both MVC and WebApi (IAuthorizationFilter in System.Web.Mvc and System.Web.Http.Filters) to centralize your custom logic.

Comment: Any tutorial on it @SimonBelanger? Looking for similar solution...

Answer (score 1):

Its a feasible option but not a recommended option.

Since WebApi operation will be inheriting from ApiController

and MVC controller action will be inheriting from Controller Class.

If you want to define route for api and mvc controller then you need to register the route like this in Global.ascx in

Application start

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

RouteConfig Class

```
    public static class RouteConfig
        {
            public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {   

    .....
    ....
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
    }
    }
```

WebApiConfig Class

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: Add any additional configuration code.

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;

            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new YourMessageHandlers());

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new {  id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```